# Parsing XML with Go not able to get value from single tag

Tags: xml, go, struct, xml-parsing

This is my first time trying to use the xml package for Go, so I assume I'm missing something.  I have this simple XML from a legacy web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<boolean xmlns="http://foo.com.BARRSD/">true</boolean>
```

I first tried defining this struct to use with the xml.Unmarshal method:

```
type Authenticate struct {
    Boolean bool `xml:"boolean"`
}
```

But I believe it's not able to "find" *boolean* so the resulting value in Boolean is the initialized value of false.  And I sanity checked that was the case by redefining Boolean as a string, and that just resulted in an empty string.  And I get the same results if I simplify the source XML even more:

```
<boolean>true</boolean>
```

How does one parse out the value of a single tag using xml.Unmarshal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your Go model does not match the XML structure. Your Go model assumes there's an "authenticate" wrapper tag, and it would would match this XML:

```
<authenticate>
    <boolean xmlns="http://foo.com.BARRSD/">true</boolean>
</authenticate>
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gc_87jpj793).

Since you don't have a wrapper tag, you may use the `,chardata` XML tag option to use the inner text for the `Boolean` field:

```
type Authenticate struct {
    Boolean bool `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FXgdwo7_YCF).

Also note that in this specific example you could also use a single `bool` variable:

```
var b bool

if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &b); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4rviEx4a1UD).